# I need to get a list of folders in one line

Tags: command-line, command, command-prompt

I have this line (simple one I know):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (List.txt) DO ECHO %%G
```

and the result is:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

(like it should)
but I need the this output:
`**AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD**`

can anyone help with such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D%20echo%20without%20new%20line)? However, the following batch-file could help as well:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

echo --- Original:
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (List.txt) DO ECHO %%G

echo --- One line:
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (List.txt) DO <NUL set /P "=%%G|"
echo(

echo --- Another one line:
set "_FirstLine="
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (List.txt) DO ( 
  if defined _FirstLine (
    <NUL set /P "=|%%G"
  ) else (
    <NUL set /P "=%%G"
    set "_FirstLine=done"
  )
)
echo(
```

**Output:** `D:\bat\SO\59459244.bat`

> ```
> --- Original:
> AAA
> BBB
> CCC
> DDD
> --- One line:
> AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD|
> --- Another one line:
> AAA|BBB|CCC|DDD
> ```

Note that the `echo(` command prints an empty line to the console (important here to exit printing in the same line after the `for` loop ends).